# MySQL: Querying values in relational tables

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "Music Charts", which is based on a YouTube video and has some general information about the uploader, the duration time, the URL etc. in its structure.

Now I want to save the contained songs. So I create another table named "Song placement" with the "URL" from the "Music Charts" table (as foreign key) and rows with the name "#1", "#2", [...], "#30" with the URL of the single songs.

Eventually, I create a third table called "song_information" to store some values about the producer, the singer and the music company, after defining "URL" from "song placement" as foreign key.

Currently, I don't know if this concept has any mistakes in it. Also I am confused about how to query values using MySQL when using three relational tables.

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: I would like to know if this concept is correct and how I am able to query "producer" in "song_information", after querying the latest entry in "Music Charts"

Comment: It is pretty difficult to tell if a design is wrong, when you do not know what purpose the design serves. Regarding the query: you need to join the 3 tables. There are several questions just here on SO alone about joins.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's better if you keep the song placement as a column in the table where you store the uploader, song duration, URL etc. Lets say you call it songs_table.

Then you create a table for example producers_table. In this table you store only inforamtions about producers, and the songs they produced.

For example this table can have this colums:

ProducerID,ProducerName,ProducerBio,ProducerDob,SongID.

SongID is the foreign key of the table Songs.

Hope this helps.